# Why deployment.apps but service (dot-nothing) in kubecfg get all?

Tags: kubernetes

When I do `kubectl get all`, I see

```
pod/something
service/something
deployment.app/something
replicaset.app/something
```

Why there's an `app` following `deployment` and `replicaset`? What does `app` mean here? What's other possible values other than `app`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `app` part is an [API Group](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/#api-groups). The Pod and Service resource belongs to the "core" API Group, so it does not have to be written.